# ¿Cómo cambiar el color StatusBar texto cordova Android e iOS?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo se puede cambiar el color de la barra de estatus en Cordova?

He utilizado el *plugin* de `StatusBar` pero solo me permite cambiar el color del *background* mediante:

```
StatusBar.backgroundColorByName("cyan");
```

Pero solo el *background* no el texto, ¿hay alguna manera de modificar eso?

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente asegura NO tener definido el estilo "Default":

```
StatusBar.styleDefault();
```

Las opciones son:

```
StatusBar.styleLightContent(); //texto claro, para fondos oscuros.

StatusBar.styleBlackTranslucent(); 

StatusBar.styleBlackOpaque();
```

Comment: Ninguno de los dos funciona, al inspeccionar me dice que `Uncaught ReferenceError: Statusbar is not defined at Channel.onDeviceReady `

Comment: Statusbar is not defined ? cuando agregas StatusBar.backgroundColorByName("cyan"); no se muestra el mismo error?

Comment: No, solo cuando pongo `Statusbar.styleHex` ó  `Statusbar.styleColor`